# Error saving data into sql server using Entity Framework after deletingcolumn

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, compiler-errors

I've deleted a column in my sql server and updated the entity framework diagram in my vs2015. However I'm getting the following error:

[image]

My table looks like this:

[image]

And my diagram in EF looks like this:

[image]

What i've tried so far:

Updating & refreshing my model in vs2015.

Deleting the particular table in my model and re-adding it by updating my model.

I've read about this problem many times but I cant find a solution that fixes mine.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Could you take a screen shot from your table and the diagram?

Comment: @SamanGholami see updated post

Comment: the error says that you are trying to save to a column called test.  don't do that.

Comment: It seems one of other tables, except `MapperConfig` table contains column called `test` in the model but it's not existed in database. I suggest you to delete all tables from model and add them again.